# Sending mail with html table format using awk command

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am trying to send mail in html table format using awk command as below:

```
(

echo "From: "

echo "Subject: testing of html table using awk"

awk 'BEGIN{print "<table>"} {print "<tr>";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print "<td>" $i"</td>";print  "</tr>"} END{print "</table>"}' file.tmp

) | sendmail xxx@yy.com
```

And my file(file.tmp) contains as below:

```
AAA 1 1 1 1 0 0

SAP 1 1 1 1 0 0

RTTC 1 1 1 1 0 0

PGW 1 1 1 1 0 0
```

But I am not getting the mail in html tabular format but instead with html code itself.

Is the AWK command correct? Or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a `Content-type` header:

```
(
    echo "From: "
    echo "Subject: testing of html table using awk"
    echo "Content-type: text/html"
    echo
    awk 'BEGIN{print "<table>"} {print "<tr>";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print "<td>" $i"</td>";print  "</tr>"} END{print "</table>"}' file.tmp
) | sendmail xxx@yy.com
```

Answer (score 0):

It is already in table format only thing is we have to give a style to the table.
This worked for me `awk '
BEGIN{
    print "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n<style>\ntable,th,td\n{\nborder:1px solid black ;   \nborder-collapse:collapse;\n}\n</style>\n</head>\n<Body>\n<table>"
    } 
    {print "<tr>"
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        print "<td>" $i"</td>"
    print "</tr>"
    }
    END{
    print "\n</table>\n</Body>\n</html>\n"
    }' a.txt >> email.html;
cat email.html | sendmail -t ananoymous@exampl.com`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify Content type for parsing html. U can also use option -F for awk which specifies the delimiter( default is space ).

```
(
    echo "Subject: $subject"
    echo "Content-type: text/html"
    echo "To:" $emailAddress
    awk 'BEGIN{print "<table border=1 cellspacing=2 cellpadding=2> {print "<tr>";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print "<td>" $i"</td>";print  "</tr>"} END{print "</table>"}' $fileName
) | sendmail -t
```