# Sending email from shell in a tabular format

Tags: shell

When sending email from shell the body of the email is in not proper way, I need the data to be in tabular format i.e

```
id        Name    loc
1         xxxx     az
2         yyyy     az
3         wwww     az
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s-nail -s subject-foobar random@example.tld<<EOF
id        Name    loc
1         xxxx     az
2         yyyy     az
3         wwww     az
EOF
```

Comment: Please explain the answer with some context to understand instead of code-only answer, that will add more value to the answer.

Comment: I judge (myself) the level of details I provide from op question/implication. Just one of `email` tool, _that just works_, and shell _here doc_.

Comment: 'not working' doesn't means anything. Have you an error ?

Comment: there is no error, but the output in the mail is not in tabular format .. i mean there is no proper space between 2 fields and rows

Comment: Found one useful link thought this might help someone too : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927710/sending-mail-with-html-table-format-using-awk-command